# How to change the MFC Menu background color?

Tags: c++, mfc

I use `OnInitMenuPopup`，and it does not work.Like this:

```
void CMainFrame::OnInitMenuPopup(CMenu *pPopupMenu, UINT nIndex, BOOL bSysMenu)
{
    HBRUSH oMenuBackgroundColor = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(233, 238, 255) );
    MENUINFO MenuInfo = { 0 };
    MenuInfo.cbSize = sizeof(MenuInfo);
    MenuInfo.hbrBack = oMenuBackgroundColor; // Brush you want to draw
    MenuInfo.fMask = MIM_BACKGROUND;

    if (IsMenu(*pPopupMenu))
    {
        SetMenuInfo(*pPopupMenu, &MenuInfo);
    }

    BOOL bEnableMnBordList = AfxGetApp()->GetProfileInt("Other", "EnableMnBordList", FALSE );
    if ( !bEnableMnBordList && pPopupMenu != NULL && pPopupMenu->GetMenuItemCount() > 0)
    {
        pPopupMenu->RemoveMenu(ID_ACC_MN_BORD_LIST, MF_BYCOMMAND);
        DrawMenuBar();
    }
}
```

But `OnInitMenuPopup` doesn't seem to be able to change the ITEM Background.

[image]

Comment: It certainly looks like it worked. It changed the background color to a light blue.

Comment: Only changes part of the menu.Another part remains gray.

Comment: That left-hand 'margin' is where menu-item bitmaps and/or check marks are drawn. Not sure how to directly change its b/g but you could possibly add a blank, square bitmap of the same colour for each item in the popup.

Comment: I know two approaches for this: 1. Draw your own custom owner drawn menus. 2. Play with VisualManager themes, by implementing your own theme. The part you are seeing gray is being painted because the Visual theme you've chosen is explicitly drawing filling it that color on your back.